# TypeError: Argument must be rect style object in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

For a while now I've been trying to teach myself how to use sprites in pygame and right now I am stuck on collision detection.

The specific place I am having trouble with in my code is the commented section labeled "error here" and that's the code that keeps giving me the "TypeError: Argument must be rect style object" error and the goal of that specific code is to detect collision.

The goal of this code is to print a message in the shell whenever the player block enters the non-player block and as I said earlier I have been having trouble getting that to happen.

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame

pygame.init()

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

plr_g = pygame.sprite.Group()
h_box = pygame.sprite.Group()

BLUE = (0, 206, 209)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, plr_g)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        #self.rect = (400, 200)


    def x_pos(self):
        self.rect.x
    def y_pos(self):
        self.rect.y
    def move_l(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
    def move_r(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
    def move_u(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
    def move_d(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels


class Hitbox(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bx, by):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, h_box)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([100, 100])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect = (bx, by)


hitbox = Hitbox(300, 300)
hitbox = Hitbox(100, 500)
player = Player(50, 50)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move_l(10)
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move_r(10)
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                player.move_u(10)
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.move_d(10)


    #error here
    if plr_g.colliderect(h_box):
        print("collide")
    #----------------

    plr_g.update()
    h_box.update()




    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
    h_box.draw(screen)
    plr_g.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

`h_box` is a sprite group, not a sprite and definitely not a rect.  The `collide_rect` function of sprites must be called on individual sprites.  A possible solution is something like the following, iterating over all the sprites in `h_box`:

```
if any([plr_g.colliderect(sp) for sp in h_box]):
    print("collide")
```

Comment: Sorry this may sound a little obvious but what does "sp" refer to?

Comment: `sp` is a temporary variable used in the list comprehension that I am performing.  It's just an abbreviation of sprite, to indicate that you are iterating over the sprite group, so each element is a sprite.

Answer (score 0):

```
block_hit_list = plr_g.colliderect(h_box)
for block in block_hit_list:
    print ("collide")
```

I basically loop through the list to see if there are any collisions between the   sprites in plr_g and the sprites in hitbox.